# maximum possible common mode voltage for npn

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, npn, common-mode

First I would like to thank everybody here for providing the help. This great resource allows me to understand things beyond what my textbook only offers.
I have the question below:

[image: Question 9.34 from "Microelectronic Circuits" by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition]

Here is the figure they are referring to in the question:

[image: Figure 9.14 from "Microelectronic Circuits" by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition]

(Source of images: ["Microelectronic Circuits" book by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition, chapter 9](http://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780199339136/))

## HERE YOU FORGET TO INSERT AN IMPORTANT ASSUMPTION

[image: vbc]

**AND IT EXPLAINS WHY YOU ARE MISSING 0.4 V** taken from sedra-smith

So using the small signal analysis model, which am not going make you bored from it, I was able to find the value to Rc = 5k ohms which totally agrees with the text book's answer. Now my struggle is to find the maximum Vcm.
Here is my analysis

\begin{equation}
V_{cm,max}=V_{BE}+V_C=0.4+V_{CC}-\frac{I}{2}R_C=0.4+5-\left(0.5mA\right)\left(5k\Omega \right)=2.9V
\end{equation}

But my book says that:

\begin{equation}
V_{cm,max}=1.6V
\end{equation}

Can somebody please tell me how that came about?? Am really confused! Thank you for your help in advance.

UPDATE 1:
Here is an LTspice simulation of the problem. Please let me know if my model is correct or not because am a beginner with LTSpice. You can see from the simulation results that change in collector voltages and currents don't happen till around vb=2.9V

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that *for which operation is as required* implies that you need to account for an additional differential output swing. I also think it's incorrect to calculate the *input* common mode range without any mention of the base (eg. a \$V_{BE}\$).
Despite this, I also can't see how the CM input range would be that limited.

Comment: You've provided a formula, not an analysis. Please provide the sound reasoning you used to reach that formula. Also, where did that 400mV come from? It's not in the text you offered. If I'm allowed to apply 400mV to the problem, I can soundly reason a case for their \$1.6\:\text{V}\$. Under no circumstances can I find a way to accept your formula. So your reasoning here would help identify your mistake.

Comment: You mainly forgot about the voltage swing at the transistor collector.

Comment: I think the problem is melting down to me adding 0.4V and you subtracting 0.4V. So my book says: \begin{equation}V_{BC}=0.4=V_B-V_C\\therefore\\ V_B=V_{cm,max}=0.4+V_C=0.4+V_{CC}-\frac{I}{2}R_C=0.4+5-\left(0.5mA\right)\left(5k\Omega \right)=2.9!!!!\end{equation} using this equation from my book only, I don't know how they are getting 1.6V???

Comment: Mine is Sedra Smith 7th edition chapter 9

Comment: @Raykh Where did you find this answer (1.6V). And who said that the books don't "make errors".

Comment: In the back of the back they provide answers but no solutions to some selected problems. There is a low probability for a mistake

Comment: @G36 can you please provide an answer using LTSPICE simulation just to make sure. Thank you very much

Comment: your model is **not correct**, what you are doing is a common mode simulation! But you also want to have a **gain**. You have to add the differential input voltage! **Look at my schematic**! Please read an take look at my post.

Comment: just changed it, hope i did it correctly. Didn't change things a whole lot

Comment: Correct the v_differential_mode voltage2 to -5mV to get correct simulation results.

Comment: @abu_bua, I just corrected my simulation model and it shows that the collector voltage wouldn't change until vb=2.5V which agrees with G36 comments. so can I conclude that this is a mistake in the book and the correct answer should be Vcm,max=2.5V???? BUT THIS IS COUNTERACTING your calculations!!!

Comment: @G36: my simulation model shows you calculations results. the collector voltage changes at vb=2.5V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Vout = 1V when you have Vin = 10mV. These values are **fully-differential**. That means at single-ended input of 5mV you have to got a 500mV change in output.

First get the g_m of one **Q1** by:

$$g_m = \cfrac{I_c}{2\cdot V_{Th}} = \cfrac{1mA}{2\cdot 25\,mV} = 20 \, mS\, ,$$

assuming that the Q1 runs at room temperature. Therefore, when we have the maximum input voltage of 5mV, you get:

$$\Delta  I_C = g_m\cdot \Delta v_{BE} = 20\, mS \cdot 5\, mV = 0.1\, mA\, .$$

To get a value of R_c, you have to remind that the voltage drop has to be 500mV:

$$R_C = \cfrac{500\, mV}{\Delta I_C}\, = 5\,k\Omega .$$

The branch with the higher current in the differential amplifier sets the maximum allowable common mode input voltage.

Looking at the circuit diagram below, you can set a voltage loop of the input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqts09.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$V_{CC} - R_C \cdot \Bigg(\cfrac{I}{2} + \Delta I_C \Bigg) - V_{BC}\ge V_{in\,\text{Common mode}} + V_{in\, \text{diff mode}} \\
5\, V  -  5\, k \cdot 0.6 \, mA + 0.4\, V\ge V_{in\,\text{Common mode}} + 5\, mV \, \\
V_{in\,\text{Common mode}} \le 2.395 \,V\quad .$$

**NOTE**:When the voltage at the collector is **higher** than the base voltage, the transistor Q1 keeps in the triode  (linear, active) region. In this textbook and as simulation shows, the base-collector diode can open until a voltage of 400mV is reached, without influencing the gain stage.

Your textbook has forgotten to include the 5mV of the max. differential input voltage. In case the gain is high, it doesn't change much, however, when the gain is low (e.g. 2), it matters! If the gain is 2, and you want to have a max. single-ended output swing of 500mV, you get a V_differential/2 of 250mV! , wich you have to add to your max. allowablecm input range.
Most textbook ignore that case!

**Here is the simulation result**

The black curve is the collector voltage of Q1, which starts to increase at a common mode input voltage of 2.45V

[image: simulation]

Comment: You are totally correct and that is the why I look at it too. As long as the collector is at a voltage higher than the base then the base-collector junction is reversed baised which makes the transistor stay in the active region. Of course this is the general case, because my book is more percise about that. It says to keep the transistor in active, Vbc<=0.4V. and that where the equation in my qestion comes from. Vb=vcm, Vc is the collector voltage already known from Vcc and Rc. Doing the mathematics, I get Vcm=2.9V and your answer is kinda close to 2V. But the book says vcm should equal 1.6V

Comment: But I still don't get how they got vcm=1.6?? am really confused and that what I posted the question for

Comment: In your original post you wrote V_CE = 400mV, should be V_BC = 400mV.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I will fix this shortly

Comment: Why did you subtracting this 0.4V? I don't get it.

Comment: So all this means the if we assumed that before transistor enters saturation region the Vbc voltage can reach 0.4V. The voltage at collector can "safety" go below the base voltage be this 0.4V. And this why Raykh textbook adds this 0.4V.

Comment: So, why you write 1.995V - 0.4V? Safety margin?

Comment: because the original poster had a Vbc = 400mV --> Vcb = -400mV. Myself I use V_bc = 0V for paper calculation - the rest or more accurate result can be got by simulation (or better measurement)

Comment: @abu_bua, thank you for your answer, but am sorry I can't follow its logic. I posted a comment above outlining what my textbook goes by, I don't think you took the time to read it. You are subtracting 0.4V and my book adds 0.4V. Am hoping someone would post a clearer answer.

Comment: In the circuit, under discussion, we have Vc1 = Vc2 = 2.5V and the voltage output swing +/-0.5V and if we ignore other factors. For Vbc=0V we have Vcm = 2.5V - 0.5V = 2V but for Vbc = 0.4V we have Vcm = 2.5V - 0.5V + 0.4V = 2.4V

Comment: Your Vc statement is right. The other: Assume Vcm is 2.4, than  the base-collector diode is **open** --> you are in saturation!!! Note: Vbc= - Vcb !!! That means you have to **substract**.

Comment: @G36 I agree with your comment more, and it seems very logical and along the route of my book footsteps, but still it does not show how they got 1.6V

Comment: What I like  to say is the following: You have to take the Transportmodell of the bipolar transistor, and you have to know that are very unsymmetric devices in terms of doping levels. Therefore beta is different in reverse and forward operation -> therefore the you have to take a Vbc into account. **Please give me the author and the title of this book!**

Comment: @abu_bua For Vcm = Vb = 2.4V to be in saturation Vc needs to be 0.4V below 2.4V right? And the book http://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/umbrella/sedrasmith/

Comment: But for Vc = 2V and Vb = 2V we have Vbc = 0V not 0.4V. I give you the link to the book website. Sedra and K.C. Smith, Microelectronic Circuits

Comment: @abu_bua I gave you the book in the comments above and G36 did so TOO. The problem is from chapter 9 and the book is 7th edition

Comment: You're answers is correct, but I can't follow it's logic according to the book's footsteps. I just don't understand why are you subtracting 0.4V where you should be adding 0.4V

Comment: @Raykh: I only assumed to have some margin. Since your answerbook says 1.6V. I didn't found that problem in my 6th edition. So it is new --> maybe an error. **further** usually a good designer doesn't calculate R_c for such a common mode issue -> he uses his brain and uses for the current the equation Id/2 * (1 + Vindif/(2*25mV) ) -- in our case 0.5mA ( 1 + 5mV/50mV) --> easy: worth to remember.

Comment: @abu_bua, thank you very much and I really appreciate your help.You might be correct that this is an error in the book. Am about to upload a simulation model for the problem using LTSpice, please take a look at it. It shows that the collector voltage and current don't change till about vb=2.9V

Comment: @abu_bua: i just added the LTspice simulation

Comment: **NO, it is correct. In this book the are assuming Vbc = 0.4V**